# How to fix Instance of Future<int> in appbar title in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, future

I would like the appBar title of my Scaffold to display the total number of items (length) in a Firebase Query at launch, but it keeps returning `Instance of 'Future<int>'`.  How can I fix this?

Here's my code:

```
Query itemList = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('simple');
      
Future<int> itemCount() async => FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('simple')
      .snapshots()
      .length;
      
...      

    return Scaffold(

            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("# Items: " + itemCount().toString()),
              
              // DISPLAYS: # Items: Instance of 'Future<int>'
```

Unfortunately, it displays `Instance of 'Future<int>'`.  What do I have to change to obtain the item count (length) and have that show-up in the title text?

Thank you!

Comment: itemCount() is async, you need to await the result before using it. Use a future builder maybe https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use a FutureBuilder like this :

```
AppBar(
    title: FutureBuilder<String>(
           future: itemCount(), 
           builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
               if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text("# Items: " + snapshot.data.toString());
               }else {
                  Text("No data");
               }
           }),
     )
```

Comment: I like where you're going with this, but  ```future: itemCount(),``` gives red squiggly error: ```The argument type 'Future<int>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<String>?'.```  Any ideas?

Comment: I changed ```itemCount()``` to return a string, which fixed the error, HOWEVER it did not work.  I still receive ```# Items: 'Instance of Future<int>'```.

Comment: @SqueezeOJ With my code you are still saving this? Printing only "snapshot.data" display something?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a "Future" function, thats the function return a Future so you cant display it like that, you need to use an await (if you are in async function) or a `.then()` (if you'r not in async function).
The best way to print it in your case is to use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) or the keyword await.

Comment: The `await` keyword won't work inside the `build()` method, which cannot be an `async` method, but the `FutureBuilder` will work well.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting, I came to the conclusion that I need to use **StreamBuilder**.  Here's the solution that fixed it:

```
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: StreamBuilder(
                stream: itemList.snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {

                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Text("# Items: ...");
                  }

                  else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Text("# Items: ${snapshot.data?.docs.length ?? 0}");
                  }

                  else {
                    return const Text('# Items: 0');
                  }

                },  // Item Builder
              ),  // Stream Builder
            ),  // App Bar
```

Screenshot of completed project with # Items in appBar title:
[image: Screenshot of completed project]

The floating action button adds items to the list and onTap deletes the selected item from the list.  The title remains updated.

*I hope this helps someone in the future.*